# Can peltier modules be more efficiant with a medium other than air?

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, cooling

Peltier modules are said to be less efficient than conventional air conditioners. Can a medium like moving cold water over the heat sink increase the efficiency of a peltier module? By how much? Another ideas is to bury the heat sink deep in the ground to cool the hot side through conduction instead of convection.

Comment: Perhaps the efficiency is limited by the function of the junction.

Comment: I would think the need for a heat sink fan could be replaced with a largert heat sink thus saving electricity. so may be a another more efficiant way to draw both heat from the hot side a cold from the cool side would also save on electricity?

Comment: Using a peltier module (inside or guts) with a larger surface area  and using a higher voltage at less amps would be more efficient? I could not find much on different configuration online.

Comment: You seem to be loosing comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful: "efficiency" usually means the ratio of energy applied to energy removed from the "cold side" object.   Since a Peltier junction has a fixed delta-T , you won't get any colder by increasing the heat-sink capability. You will get to the cold limit faster, or even get to a lower temperature if you use cold water instead of room-temp air.
The only way to get a greater delta-T is to stack junctions.

BTW, there's a pretty good discussion of Peltier coolers [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162393/6w-12v-5a-peltier-only-drawing-1a-i-am-supplying-more-current-but-its-only-draw) , where the practical limits of drive current are explained.